# Is it possible to define a Scala function that can only be accessed from another trait?

Tags: scala

private[] or protected[] access modifier definitely won't help. Is this feature currently missing?

Comment: It's not a missing feature, it's deliberately not present. You can only restrict a function to something containing that function; anything else would be, frankly, insane (a function inherently has access to itself as it can do anything itself can; that should be reflected in the access control).

Comment: a function can also be public and be accessed from anywhere, this feature is merely an intermediate state between public and protected, it won't cause broken mechanic IMHO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to do it with method access restrictions defined in language, but you can emulate it with implicit arguments

```
  // A.scala
  trait A {
    def foo(i: Int)(implicit accessKey: B.AccessKey) = {
      println(s"A = $i")
    }
  }

  // B.scala
  object B {
    sealed trait AccessKey
  }

  trait B {
    private[B] implicit object AccessKeyInstance extends AccessKey

    def bar(a: A) = a.foo(10)
  }

  // C.scala
  trait C {
    def bar(a: A) = a.foo(20) // Implicit not found error
  }
```

You can place only one implicit instance of AccessKey in trait B, and trait C will not be able to access it.

However this trick doesn't work if you place traits B and C in single scala file; in this case you'll be able to create a second instance of AccessKey.